# Quickblox is not working with subdomain url

Tags: angularjs, quickblox

I have multiple URL for same domain , but its contain sub domain like following

```
admin.projectname.com 
doctor.projectname.com
etc..
```

Here quickblox call not working with this URLs and giving following error:

```
NavigatorUserMediaError {
    name: "PermissionDeniedError",
    message: "Only secure origins are allowed.",
    constraintName: ""
} app.js:577 4
```

I have refer quickblox and found some solution like quickblox only work with **localhost** and **https SSL** but I want to make it work with this type of URL.

It is already working with localhost but I want to start it with virtual domain of localhost.

Please help me out of this. let me know if any query.

Comment: Are you still trying to develop locally? Could add an entry to your `.hosts` file? something like `127.0.0.1 admin.projectname.com`?

Comment: Yes i have created virtual domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get access to UserMedia unless you're connected to a secure host. Your browser recognizes as secure host the ones with HTTPS or, for development, localhost.

If you need to develop with full domain names you either generate an SSL certificate (a free self-signed) for your environment or use an obscure flag like `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="admin.projectname.com"`.

See https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins section *Testing a Powerful Feature*.

Comment: Yes , i have created SSL certificate and set it to all virtual domain and its working now...